# using __dirname to access two different public/views folder

Tags: angularjs, dirname

I have two different public folders for two type of users. How can I set __dirname to access the routes by some prefix? My directory structure is as:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found an answer.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../users'));
```